# how to evenly space numbers within a range, in F#

Tags: arrays, parallel-processing, f#

I have some range of real numbers, in a 2D array:

```
[
    [ 100; 200;  -50 ]
    [ 200; 800;  200 ]
    [  80; -150; 300 ]
]
```

and a constant:

100

I would like to take all numbers and map them, in a 2D array to the [0 .. constant - 1] rang where:

- the bottom half is for the negative numbers
- the upper half is for the positive numbers

Now, here's the trick: I don't want them to be spaced based on their value, but based on how many unique values there are:

For example, let's focus on the positive range. We have:

```
[ 100; 200; 200; 800; 200; 80; 300 ]
```

We can turn that into a sorted set:

```
[ 80; 100; 200; 300; 800 ]
```

So the mapping would be:

```
[ 50; 62; 74; 86; 99 ]
```

It starts at 50 since it's the positive range, and expands through the available numbers (50) in order to fill the destination range.

So I can calculate a dictionary that becomes a mapping table from the source 2D array and then do a map to the destination 2D array doing lookups.

But, here is the catch:

I've to do this on 700mb of floats in a process that tries to output data as fast as possible.

I don't know how much could be done in parallel (besides splitting positive and negative) but I am looking for a speed optimized solution.
I'm not sure how fast dictionary lookups could be.

The answer doesn't have to be compilable code, what I'm looking for is the right approach.

Comment: Is anything known about the distribution of the numbers? In particular with regards to the float numbers. I think the answer to that question will have a huge impact on which method is optimal.

Comment: it's financial data, and is typically between -2k and +2k, but inside that range, it's very random. There are some clusters of almost identical number, and some a widely different; sometimes I can have one number maybe 20% of the array, sometimes, it's very varied. There may be less than 100 numbers in the set, but it could also be thousands.

Comment: How many significant digits do you need to consider when  you compare the values?

Comment: This is variable as the source values need to be mapped in the range determined by the constant which is always less than 300. If the values span between -2k to +2k, and cover a range of 300 slots, the precision is very different than if the values go between 500 and 520 for example and we have 100 slots to represent them. The essence is to spread the source range as must as possible in the destination range.